# Bug in just released 1.5?

Tags: android, android-studio

Working on Linux.

Android Studio 1.4 told me that 1.5 is available in the **stable** channel;
I upgraded.

Afterward, 1.5 seems to be "looking" for Gradle 2.4; yet 2.8 seems to be what's actually installed.

More details:

1. After the upgrade, the Gradle sync failed on the project I opened.
2. Error message:
   .../android-studio/gradle/gradle-2.4/lib/plugins/gradle-diagnostics-2.4.jar (No such file or directory)
3. But the version specific sub-directory within the gradle directory is gradle-2.8
4. The update procedure itself did not complain about any issues.
5. The update was done without any open projects; update was done from the main Studio panel.
6. After the update of Studio itself, via "Configure" from main panel went to "SDK Manager", then updated to newest compatible SDK.

Has anyone else had a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there was a problem in this update.

Open file **gradle-wrapper.properties** in your project using Android view:

[image]

Just change the version 2.4 to 2.8:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks crubio!  Sooner or later that would have affected me.  Now you've got me thinking I need to do a recursive grep through the install directories to find other possible version related problems...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - it seems some of the Gradle components were on the classpath for the JVM which studio itself uses; somehow the JVM didn't exit when Studio was to have re-started after the update.  Once I bought that down and restarted Studio, the JVM and all, Studio 1.5 seems to be working just fine so far.

Sorry for the interruption to your regularly scheduled development!

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely some issue with the upgrade as I also faced the same problem.
Although restarting the system (Mac) fixed it.